# Escaping single and double quotes while displaying dynamic text in textbox using PHP

Tags: php, string

I want to display text in html form(text field) that comes from DB so I used following code

```
....
.....
<input type="text" name="txtqname" id="txtqname" value="<?=$myvar ?>"></input>
....
.....
```

Here $myvar is variable whose value comes form DB and that may contains single or double quotes. Because of this my text is not properly displayed in text field as I want. I tried to replace double quotes with single as

```
....
.....
<input type='text' name='txtqname' id='txtqname' value='<?=$myvar ?>'></input>
....
.....
```

but still I don't get proper text. Please help me.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is your friend

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple, all you have to do is:

```
<input type="text" name="txtqname" id="txtqname" value="<?= htmlspecialchars( $myvar ) ?>"></input>
```

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is a useful function, Thanks for sharing. +1 for your answer

Answer (score 3):

Just use `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()`

http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use proper [addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) and [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) for formatting data. 
Make sure every data is properly formatted before inserting into database. Also try this mysql_real_escape_string()

Answer (score 0):

You can use htmlentities function with ENT_QUOTES,

Ex: htmlentities($myvar, ENT_QUOTES);

ENT_QUOTES  Will convert both double and single quotes.